# How to get people to the fishing island in Cities Skylines?

Tags: cities-skylines

There is a Fishing Island under the Parks section in Cities Skylines. People come to it but never visit the island. How to make them do? [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe it's possible for Cims to visit the actual island itself. There are [several](https://steamcommunity.com/app/255710/discussions/0/1488866180614150975/) [existing](https://www.reddit.com/r/CitiesSkylines/comments/7alhih/people_visit_the_fishing_pier_and_floating/) [threads](https://steamcommunity.com/app/255710/discussions/0/1499000547491296137/) on reddit and Steam about this topic.